# PHP infinite redirect

Tags: php, loops, authentication, content-management-system, infinite

I am trying to solve a problematic piece of code on a website I did not write. The owner is trying to login to the CMS administration on his site, but the login form leads only to the infinite redirect loop. It is a custom CMS written by someone else, but the guy cut off any communication with the owner and is working now for rival company (so looks like a sabotage), well so the owner asked me to try to solve it up. But as soon as I am not a PHP expert and the code is not written by me, I am stuck and also I don't want to break his site entirely (I am not a professional and I am doing it as a favor).

Here is the code of the page which I think is making the problem: the infinite loop is happening to: `/admin/login?login=true`.

```
    <?php
if (!defined('APP_DOMAIN')) {header('Location: http://google.com', true); exit();}

/**
 * Zavádzacia class pre admin ako taký.
 * @author --
 * @version 1.0
 * @package Bsystem
 * @todo jazyk bude spoplatneny, podla toho bude aj iny ako SK
 */
class admin
{
    /**
     * @var array Tu su ulozene vsetky premenne, ktore sa prenasaju do inych
     * tried
     */
    private $vars = array(
        'admin_page_landing' => FALSE,
        'admin_page_request' => FALSE,
        'admin_page_request_num' => FALSE,
        'admin_page_request_last' => FALSE,
        'admin_config' => FALSE,
        'admin_page_login' => FALSE,
        'admin_page_lost' => FALSE,
        'web_config' => FALSE,
        'post_action' => FALSE,
    );

    /**
     * Platnosť nastavím na max, ale max doba prihlásenia je APP_COOKIE_LIFETIME
     *  to koli tomu aby im vždy vypísalo že vypršal čas prihlásenia než sa
     *  zmaže _SESSION
     */
    public function __construct() {
        //error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
        header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
        header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.
        mb_internal_encoding(APP_CHARSET);
        ini_set('session.cookie_domain', APP_COOKIE_DOMAIN);
        // je vetsi o hodinu, aby mu ukazalo ze vyprsal cas prihalsenia
        ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
        ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);
        session_set_cookie_params(86400);
        error_reporting(1);
        //error_reporting(E_WARNING);
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset='.APP_CHARSET.'');
        session_start();
        $this->vars['post_action'] = APP_DOMAIN.substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
    }

    /**
     * Takze tu vparsujem seo, _get, _post a prazdne indexy sa zmazu
     * @global Object $user
     */
    public function router() {
        global $user;

        // parsovanie SEO
        $request = rest::requestUrlCompile(str_replace(
                'admin/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
         // parsovanie _GET + ich validacia

        if ($user->user_logged == TRUE) {
            // odhlasenie
            if ($request[1] == 'logout') {
                $user->logoutUser();
                header('Location: '.APP_DOMAIN.'admin/login', TRUE);
            } elseif ($request[1] == 'login') {
                header('Location: '.APP_DOMAIN.'admin/', TRUE);
            } elseif ($request[1] == 'lost') {
                header('Location: '.APP_DOMAIN.'admin/', TRUE);
            } else {
                // ziskanie id/stranky/cislovania/strankovania       
                if (is_numeric($request[sizeof($request)])) {
                    $this->vars['admin_page_request_num'] = $request[sizeof($request)];
                    // vymazeme cislo
                    unset($request[sizeof($request)]);
                }
                // nastavenie admin_page_request_last
                $this->vars['admin_page_request_last'] = $request[sizeof($request)];
                if (sizeof($request) == 0) {
                    // @todo ak je uvodka, skocit na view ? Treba nacitat este aj
                    // take srandy ako statistiky a podobne...
                    header('Location: '.APP_DOMAIN.'admin/module');
                    exit();
                    $this->vars['admin_page_landing'] = true;
                } else {
                    $this->vars['admin_page_request'] = $request;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($request[1] == 'login') {
                if (sizeof($request) > 1) {
                    header('Location: '.APP_DOMAIN.'admin/login?error=user_must_login', TRUE);
                    exit;
                } else {
                    $this->vars['admin_page_login'] = TRUE;
                }
            } elseif ($request[1] == 'lost') {
                // vygenerovanie hesla na požiadavku z emailu
                if (isset($request[2])) {
                    if (strlen($request[2]) == 64 && preg_match('/[a-f0-9]/', $request[2])) {
                        $user->lostUserGenerate($request[2]);
                    } else {
                        header('Location: '.APP_DOMAIN.'admin/lost', TRUE);
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                $this->vars['admin_page_lost'] = TRUE;
            } else {
                // presmernovanie na login
                header('Location: '.APP_DOMAIN.'admin/login?error=user_must_login', TRUE);
                exit;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Nastavenie jazyka
     */
    public function language() {
        $_SESSION[LANGUAGE_SESSION] = LANGUAGE_DEFAULT;
    }

    /**
     * Všeobecné spustenie configov
     */
    public function config() {
        $this->setWebConfig();
    }

    /**
     * Nastavenie web configu
     * @return array $this->vars['web_config']
     */
    private function setWebConfig() {
        $config = webModel::getWebConfig();
        $this->vars['web_config'] = $config[0];
    }

    public function controller() {
        if ($this->vars['admin_page_landing'] == TRUE) {
            // uvodka
            require_once '../'.APP_CONTROLLER.'indexAdminController.php';
            $controller = new indexAdminController($this->vars);
            $this->view($controller->view.'.php');
        } else {
            // hladat controller podla request atd
            if (file_exists('../'.APP_CONTROLLER.$this->vars['admin_page_request'][1].
                    '/'.$this->vars['admin_page_request'][1].'AdminController.php')) {
                require_once '../'.APP_CONTROLLER.$this->vars['admin_page_request'][1].
                    '/'.$this->vars['admin_page_request'][1].'AdminController.php';
                $controller_name = $this->vars['admin_page_request'][1].'AdminController';
                $controller = new $controller_name($this->vars);
                $vars = $controller->loadVars();
                foreach ($vars as $num => $key) {
                    if (!isset($this->vars[$key])) {
                        $this->vars[$key] = $controller->$key;
                    }
                }
                $this->view($controller->view.'.php');
            } else {
                throw new Exception('[ERROR load] controller \''.$this->vars['admin_page_request'][1].'\'
                   doesn\'t exists!');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Zobrazenie súborov, treba to nie len v controlleri ale aj tu na niektoré
     * súbory. Prehľadnejšie sa to potom robí ako priamo includovať.
     * @param type $file nazov suboru ktory sa zobrazi
     * @param type $error ak je nejaky error, napr 404, zavola sa dany subor
     * @throws Exception Ak $file aj $error su NULL
     * @global Object $user
     */
    public function view($file = NULL, $error = NULL) {
        global $user;
        // načitanie premenných aby to nešlo cet $this
        foreach (array_keys($this->vars) as $key => $name) {
            $$name = $this->vars[$name];
        }
        require_once '../'.APP_APP.'functions_admin.php';
        if (isset($error)) {
            switch ($error) {
                case 404 :
                    require_once '../'.APP_VIEW.WEB_ERROR_404;
                break; 
            }
            // za každým errorom to terminatneme
            exit();
        } else if (isset($file)) {
            require_once '../'.APP_VIEW.$file;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('[ERROR input] variable $file and $error is empty!');
        }
    }

    public function multiLang($lang = NULL) {
        if (!empty($lang)) {
            if (defined('LANGUAGE') && strpos($this->vars['web_config']['web_language'], $lang) !== FALSE) {
                return TRUE;
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }

    public function __get($var) {
        if (isset($this->vars[$var])) {
            return $this->vars[$var];
        } else {
            throw new Exception('[ERROR output] var '.$var.' doesn\'t exist!');
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't see any redirect to that specific path, maybe try "die-debugging" (inserting `die('smth')`) into different places to catch and intercept the actual redirect to that path. That should help as code itself is the crazy mix of ifs

Comment: Add your .htaccess file. Most of the infinite redirects happen because users are being redirected in different files, not in one file only. Also did it happen recently or it never worked? Can you see what has changed?